# How do I register a snapshot backed AMI in AWS using AWS tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I try to do it this way:

```
aws ec2 register-image --architecture x86_64 \
  --description XXX --name XXX \
  --sriov-net-support simple --ena-support \
  --virtualization-type hvm \
  --block-device-mappings \
    '[{"DeviceName": "/dev/sda","Ebs": {"SnapshotId": "snap-XXXX"}}]' \
  --root-device-name /dev/sda1
```

and I have this error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidBlockDeviceMapping)
when calling the RegisterImage operation: Invalid device name /dev/sda
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The block device mapping in Hardware virtual machine (HVM) AMIs can differ depending on the AMI.

I believe if you try a block address such as `/dev/xvdb` that it will work correctly.

Reference: [AWS Docs: Device Naming on Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html)